# C#のclassでスコープが明記されていないメソッドについて

Tags: c#

C#入門者です。

```
public class Sample
{

  public void Hoge(){} 

  void Fuga(){} 

}
```

上記のコードの`Sample.Hoge()`と`Sample.Fuga()`の違いはなんでしょうか。
publicやprivateなどがないとき、どのような扱いになるのでしょうか。
また、どのような場合にこういった書き方が必要になるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

`Fuga()` は`private` として扱われます。
[アクセシビリティ レベル (C# リファレンス)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

> メンバー宣言にアクセス修飾子の指定がない場合には、既定のアクセシビリティ(リンク先の表からprivateが既定)が使用されます。

必要というより単に好みの問題かと思います。（いちいち書きたくない、自分の中ではprivateとはっきりしているとか・）

Answer (score 1):

メソッドの場合は省略するとprivateと同じ扱いになります。つまり下記と同じ意味です。

```
  private void Fuga(){}
```

詳細はMSDNなどが参考になると思います。

- [アクセス修飾子 (C# プログラミング ガイド)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms173121.aspx)
- [実装の隠蔽 - C# によるプログラミング入門 | ++C++; // 未確認飛行 C](http://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/oo_conceal.html#level)

省略する理由はおそらく様々だと思いますが、例えばUnityの場合はUnityが出力するC#スクリプトの雛形ではすでにprivateを省略されているため、Unityのプロジェクトのスクリプトではprivateを省略する書き方をよく見かける気がします。